# How does the piercing mod interact with the piercing ammo power?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Do the piercing ammo power and the piercing mod for weapons stack or does one take precedence over the other?

Comment: @Sterno I don't quite think this is a dupe. The other question focuses on the mechanics of piercing and the piercing mod, but doesn't address at all whether or not the piercing stacks with the piercing ammo power, which is what this question asks.

Comment: That's right, I did see the other question but it didn't address what I'm trying to decide, which is whether or not its worth it to put a piercing mod on my weapon if I already have piercing ammo.

Comment: You are both absolutely right. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do not, reading over the mod's specifications and uses makes for no damage boost whatsoever. This may be patched soon.
I have tried this and confirmed on the Xbox.

Comment: hi Equimus, welcome to the site.  Do you have any sources for this or did you test it in game?  If you tested it, please state it in your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I tested, on xbox

Answer (score 1):

They don't interact

The piercing mod does 60%(default) less damage

But the piercing ammo does not suffer a penalty

Comment: so just to clarify, if I have the piercing ammo skill I shouldn't use piercing mods at all

Comment: Yes,because there are other,more usefull mods that you can put on your weapons!